# Create index in Aerospike configuration(aerospike.conf)

Tags: aerospike

Aerospike [reference](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/indexes/#static-configuration-for-index-management)
specify that there are static configuration for indices.

Is there a way to create secondary index via the configuration ?

similar to :

```
asinfo  -v "sindex-create:ns=ns;set=set;indexname=bin;indexdata=name,STRING"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not, but you can write a wrapper script to handle starting up your server and then applying any asinfo commands that apply to your model.

Comment: Some of the asinfo commands dosen't run because there is a startup time, how can i invoke this scrip only after the AS is up?

Comment: Also AS is running inside of a Docker container

Comment: There's a specific line you can check for in the log to see if the node is ready. The Travis-CI config for the Python client uses this script, for example: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/blob/master/scripts/wait-for-node.sh